# Connecting to an ethereum node from meteor server side

Tags: meteor, connections, server-side

I get the error TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a function when I try to connect to a node on the server side of my meteor application.

The error is caused by meteor using the meteor [HTTP package](http://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html) instead of XMLHttpRequest. [From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965055/using-the-xmlhttprequest-object-in-a-meteor-package).

How else can a meteor app connect to an ethereum node from the server side?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Bumblebee no im still trying

Comment: Meteor uses a different http module https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html and here is an issue on [we3js #579](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/579)

Comment: @niksmac could you explain a bit further- what do I need to do to get it working?

Comment: Simply put, its not a web3 related issue. If you can use the web3 js outside the scope of Meteor; it might work, idk. Never used Meteor.

Comment: @niksmac I'm not sure how the linked question is supposed to help they don't really solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found the solution. I followed this guide and it worked.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#usage

Web3 has to be decleared like this:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
```

and then you can create an instance of Web3 like this:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));        
};
```

I hope this helps